# Файл не видит класс с подключением к базе данных

Tags: php, классы

Есть файл index.php, который лежит в корне, в нём подключается файл с подключением к базе, чтобы его было видно во сём файле:

```
require_once(ROOT.'/components/Db.php');
```

Вот файл Db.php:

```
class Db
{

        public static function getConnection()
        {
            $paramsPath = ROOT . '/config/db_params.php';
            $params = include($paramsPath);


            $dsn = "mysql:host={$params['host']};dbname={$params['dbname']};charset=UTF8";
            $db = new PDO($dsn, $params['user'], $params['password']);

            return $db;
        }
}
```

Есть файл (lorem.php), который делает запросы к базе данных , в нём есть подключение к базе:

```
$db = Db::getConnection();
```

И вот когда я уже в другой файл (ipsum.php) включаю lorem.php, с помощью:

```
require_once("/lorem.php");
```

То в нём врзникает проблема, выдаёт ошибку: **Fatal ERROR: Class 'Db' not found in D:\wamp\www\models\lorem.php**  Хотя если отследить цепочку передавания класса Db: Db.php --> index.php --> lorem.php -x-> ipsum.php то всё должно быть нормально. Подскажите, в чём проблема ?

Comment: уточните:
1) как файл lorem.php связан с index.php (точнее с db.php). 2) работают ли запросы в самом файле lorem.php

Comment: @Alex Lorem.php связан с index.php тем, что index это фронт контроллер, единая точка входа. Всё что прописано там - видно во всём файле. В index.php вызван файл с классом Db. И вот lorem.php обращается к вызванному в index.php классу Db. 2)Запросы работают везде отлично, кроме этого файла (ipsum.php).

Comment: если "index это фронт контроллер, единая точка входа и Всё что прописано там - видно во всём файле", то "require_once("/lorem.php");" никак не влияет на видимость Db, потому что в lorem.php нет инклуда файла базы данных. Здесь нужен require_once("/ipsum.php"); в index.php или в каком-нибудь подключённом к нему файле.